# How to extract a value from a promise when called synchronously using Javascript `await`?

Tags: javascript, jquery, async-await, jquery-deferred

I'm working on a project that uses a custom user prompt using jQuery / jQuery UI:

```
function dialog_confirm(dialog_body, dialog_title = 'Confirm') {
  var def = $.Deferred();
  
  $('<div></div>').dialog({
    modal: true,
    title: dialog_title,
    open: function () {
      $(this).html(dialog_body);
    },
    buttons: {
      OK: function () {
        $(this).dialog("close");
        def.resolve();
      },
      Cancel: function () {
        $(this).dialog("close");
        def.reject();
      }
    }
  });
    
  return def.promise();
}
```

I didn't write the above function, and I'm not able to make changes to it unless the changes are sure not to interfere with any other calls to this function elsewhere in the code.

I'm currently working on some functionality to save details of products, but prior to saving, some checks are performed:

```
save_product(current_product_details);

function save_product(product_details) {
    let price_verified = check_price(product_details['price']);
    if (!price_verified) {
      return;
    }

    // Proceed here to save product details to DB
}

function check_price(price) {
  var proceed = true;
  
  if (price == 0) {
    proceed = false;
    
    dialog_confirm('Price is zero. Save anyway?').done(function() {
      proceed = true;
    });
  }
  
  return proceed;
}
```

Now, the above code doesn't work, because if the price is 0, and the user is prompted to confirm, the `check_price` function doesn't wait for the user's response, it just returns false, and the calling function, `save_product` just returns without saving the product. The user may well click OK, but nothing happens in any case.

So I was investigating ways to make the code wait for the user's response and came across the concepts of `async` functions and `await`. [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Promises#async_and_await) says:

> Inside an async function, you can use the await keyword before a call
> to a function that returns a promise. This makes the code wait at that
> point until the promise is settled, at which point the fulfilled value
> of the promise is treated as a return value, or the rejected value is
> thrown.

So I'm trying to refactor my code around that concept, but I can't quite figure out the return values and how to extract something meaningful from the function calls...

```
save_product(current_product_details);

async function save_product(product_details) {
    let price_verified = await check_price(product_details['price']);
    if (!price_verified) {
      return;
    }

    // Proceed here to save product details to DB
}

async function check_price(price) {
  if (price == 0) {
    try {
      let return_value = await dialog_confirm('Price is zero. Save anyway?');
      return return_value;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Do something in this case?');
    }
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

I'm quite aware that my understanding has broken down somewhere - around promises and resolving/rejecting them - but I'd appreciate some pointers on how to get this working.

Comment: So you expect `check_price` to return (a promise for) `true` when the dialog is confirmed and `false` when it is cancelled?

Comment: @Bergi yes. Well, I'd like it to just return true or false, and internally, wait for the promise from `dialog_confirm()` to be settled - but I'm imagining `dialog_confirm()` returning a promise for true/false.

Comment: That's not possible, you cannot block and wait for some asynchronous event; you cannot immediately return a boolean since the user will not click on the dialog until later.

Comment: Anyway, the problem is that `return_value` is `undefined` since your promise is not resolved with anything, and also in case of a rejection/error (from the cancel button) your function doesn't `return` anything at all but only logs to the console. See @Nam's answer for the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you getting `undefined` for your `return_value`? I'm not familiar with `JQuery` but I think since you have `def.resolve()`, this will return `void` (kinda like `Promise.resolve()`). And `def.reject()` will throw an `Error` (Kinda like Promise.reject()). So what you can do is:

```
async function check_price(price) {
  if (price == 0) {
    try {
      await dialog_confirm('Price is zero. Save anyway?');
      return true;
    } catch (error) {
      return false;
    }
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```